# How to parse heterogenous markup with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, syntax, markup

I have a string with custom markup for saving songs with chords, tabulatures, notes etc. It contains

things in various brackets: `\[.+?\]`, `\[[.+?\]]`, `\(.+?\)`
arrows: `<-{3,}>`, `\-{3,}>`, `<\-{3,}`
and so on...

Sample text might be

```
Text Text [something]
--->
Text (something 021213)
```

Now I wish to parse the markup into array of tokens, objects of corresponding classes, which would look like (matched parts in brackets)

```
ParsedBlock_Text ("Text Text ")
ParsedBlock_Chord ("something")
ParsedBlock_Text (" ")
ParsedBlock_NewColumn
ParsedBlock_Text (" text ")
ParsedBlock_ChordDiagram ("something 021213")
```

I know how to match them, but either I must match each different pattern, and save offsets to properly sort the array, or I match them at once and I don't know which one has been matched.

Thanks, MK

Comment: Don't start such complex parsing task by a regex approach. That would become a horrible nightmare soon. Look for a "compiler-compiler" or a "parser generator" instead, some tool to use a formal syntax grammar to compile the markup into an internal structure. That way you can use a ready-to-use engine without doind all the classical mistakes once more and you force yourself to define a real syntax for the markup. "Lime" might be a starting point: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lime-php/

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into it, seems like more logical approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do not try to nest these structures, this will tokenize your text:

```
function ParseText($text) {
    $re = '/\[\[(?P<DoubleBracket>.*?)]]|\[(?P<Bracket>.*?)]|\((?P<Paren>.*?)\)|(?<Arrow><---+>?|---+>)/s';
    $keys = array('DoubleBracket', 'Bracket', 'Paren', 'Arrow');
    $result = array();
    $lastStart = 0;
    if (preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $start = $match[0][1];
            $prefix = substr($text, $lastStart, $start - $lastStart);
            $lastStart = $start + strlen($match[0][0]);
            if ($prefix != '' && !ctype_space($prefix)) {
                $result []= array('Text', trim($prefix));
            }
            foreach ($keys as $key) {
                if (isset($match[$key]) && $match[$key][1] >= 0) {
                    $result []=  array($key, $match[$key][0]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $prefix = substr($text, $lastStart);
    if ($prefix != '' && !ctype_space($prefix)) {
        $result []= array('Text', trim($prefix));
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Example:**

```
$mytext = <<<'EOT'
Text Text [something]
--->
Text (something 021213)
More Text
EOT;

$parsed = ParseText($mytext);
foreach ($parsed as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Text
    [1] => Text Text
)
Array
(
    [0] => Bracket
    [1] => something
)
Array
(
    [0] => Arrow
    [1] => --->
)
Array
(
    [0] => Text
    [1] => Text
)
Array
(
    [0] => Paren
    [1] => something 021213
)
Array
(
    [0] => Text
    [1] => More Text
)
```

http://ideone.com/kJQrBw

If you want to add more patterns to the regex, make sure you put longer patterns at the start, so they are not mistakenly matched as the wrong type.