# .NET regex expression to find enclosed text

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to replace all occurrences of strings enclosed in simple markers with markup syntax. For example: I need to convert strings which looks like these:

```
"this text needs to be displayed **bold**"

"**this** text **needs** to be displayed **bold**"
```

to these:

```
"this text needs to be displayed <bold>bold</bold>"

"<bold>this</bold> text <bold>needs</bold> to be displayed <bold>bold</bold>"
```

If I use the following:

```
string inputString = "this text needs to be displayed **bold**";
var reg = new Regex(@"\*\*([^\*]+)\*\*");
var outputString = reg.Replace(inputString, match => "<bold>" + match.Value + "</bold>");
```

the output string looks like this:

```
"this text needs to be displayed <bold>**bold**</bold>"
```

In other words, **match.Value** includes the asterisks.

I've identified one other regular expression I could use:

```
(?<=\*\*).+?(?=\*\*)
```

This produces a correct first match, but is incorrect for subsequent matches; as used in the above code snippet, I get the following sequence of matches (**match.Value**) for the second example string:

```
this
 text 
needs
 to be displayed
bold
```

It seems to be returning every occurrence of a string falling between pairs of asterisks rather than "pairing" them up as needed.

If I use an online regex tool like **rubular**, my initial solution appears to do the right thing (asterisks are stripped off the matches), but that is not what is returned by the .NET implementation.

Is there a regex string I can use to achieve the result I'm after, or do I have to do some post-processing of the matches?

Comment: I am very sorry, but this will never work in a robust fashion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358582/how-to-parse-heterogenous-markup-with-php#comment23436666_16358582 for a hint on why. If you want it solid, forget regexp and write a stateful parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference the capturing group inside of the replacement call.

```
var outputString = reg.Replace(inputString, "<bold>$1</bold>");
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/4Yydum)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, for a little more control, I prefer to use the overloaded version of [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that uses a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate:

```
Regex.Replace(input,
              @"\*\*(?<a>.*?)\*\*",
              m => string.Format("<bold>{0}</bold>", m.Groups["a"].Value))
```

although for such a simple task:

```
Regex.Replace(input,
              @"\*\*(?<a>.*?)\*\*", 
              @"<bold>${a}</bold>")
```

would suffice

Comment: A very useful but lesser known delegate overload